# How to load page html and content (such as images) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jQuery, I know I can use the $.ajax function to load a page's html from a given URL.
However, I'm interested in loading the htmla nd all *resources* on that page before displaying it. How would I go about doing that?

Example:
Say I have the following html in a file called about.html

```
<h1>About BigImage</h1>
<img src="/images/reallybigimage.jpg" />
```

Notice that I have an image in this page. Using jQuery's ajax function, I would get a "success" as soon as the HTML finished loading, but not the image.

Here's the kicker, though: I don't know how many/which images I'll have in the page, and it's not just images I want to be loading -- it's all the page's resources -- css and all.
Any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If relative paths are not a problem, in your `success` function, you can then attempt to find all of the links and load them like this:

```
//....
success:function(data){
    $("*",data).each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("src")){
            $.ajax({url:$(this).attr("src"),dataType:"text"});
        }
        if($(this).attr("href")){
            $.ajax({url:$(this).attr("href"),dataType:"text"});
        }
    });
}
//....
```

Answer (score 3):

Within the success callback, convert the html to a document fragment, then select the pieces of it that you wish to preload and preload them. I won't include the code to do the actual pre-loading because that should be a question of it's own and there are plugins that already exist to do just that.

```
$.ajax(options).done(function(html){
    var $html = $(html),
        imgArr = $.map($html.find("img"),function(img) {
           return this.src;
        }),
        cssArr = $.map($html.find("link"),function(link) {
           return this.href;
        });
    // loop through and preload images and css.
    ...
    // once all are done loading, append to page.
    $("#content").html($html);
});
```

You shouldn't need to preload the scripts, however you may want to detach them and append them to the body after you append the content.

Comment: Wouldn't this only preload images and CSS files?

Comment: correct, javascript doesn't necessarily need to be preloaded, it just needs to be included on the page after the html is appended to the target div.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you are downloading (or how sure you are about the format). It also depends on what do you want to download.

You could for example use RegExp like `/<img[^>]*src(["'])([^"']+)\1[^>]*>/g`. Then you could simple use a catching function like `function (a, q, src){var i = new Image(src)}`.

You could also attach the downloaded document fragment to DOM document fragment and work on it with DOM. This might consume more resources thou.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
 $("body").load("page.html")
```

(edit:)
Or do you want to store the pagecontent into a variable? This is possible with $.ajax:

```
     $.ajax({
      url: "page.html",
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
var pagecontents = data;

}
    });
```

Comment: Not sure why people are down voting. I think that's what he wants but he will probably stick it in an element that's detached from the HTML.

Comment: How does this address preloading all of the images css and scripts of the loaded page?

Comment: Alright, got it. Ignore my post, your code is way better. Sorry!

Comment: Basically, he wants to know that the image is loaded before he appends it to the DOM, however the image doesn't start loading until after you append it to the DOM. The workaround is to preload it.